# Query local parquet using presto

Tags: parquet, presto

Using spark and drill, I am able to query local parquet files.

Does presto provide the same capability? 
In other words, is it possible to query local parquet files using presto - without going through HDFS or hive?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a straightforward way to do this. This has been long time now and I am not sure if there are other options available at the moment.

What I did was; create a custom hive meta store that would return the schemas, tables with paths of my parquet files. In presto, configured it using that meta store and that worked pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, Presto's localfile is only for http_request_logs (which is why they have settings for: `presto-logs.http-request-log.location`). I wasn't able to query local parquet data with Presto.

I was able to query data using Apache Drill. Out of the box, you can switch out the below directory with your local file system and run regular SQL on it:

```
# Start with /bin/drill-embedded
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select * from dfs.`/somedir/withparquetfiles/`
```

Comment: Thanks @Will, yes I was also able to do that. I also was able to query files from presto by implementing a custom Hive metastore that point presto to my own files.